# Rails: How to pass value from textfield to a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I easily pass the value I get from the auto_complete textfield to a partial.

```
<%= text_field_with_auto_complete :participant, :name, {}, {:url => {:controller => "contentcom/discussions", :action => :get_users_for_auto_complete}, :method => :get, :param_name => 'search'} %>
        <%= button_to_function(:OK) do |page|
                page.insert_html :top, :participants, :partial => 'participant', :locals =>  end %>
```

Bye,

Nico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to know that the helpers `text_field_with_auto_complete` and `button_to_function` not really handle user actions, but only generate HTML and javascript code. Only generated javascript code can interact with the user. In this case `text_field_with_auto_complete` generates the following (approximately):

```
<input type="text" id="participant_name" name="participant[name]" size="15" />
<div id="participant_name_auto_complete" class="auto_complete"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var participant_auto_completer = new Ajax.Autocompleter (
    'Participant',
    'Name',
    '/contentcom/discussions/get_users_for_auto_complete',
    {method: 'GET', param_name: 'search'}
  );
</script>
```

The above code is that the user gets in his browser. 
If you read the [documentation](http://github.com/rails/auto_complete/blob/master/lib/auto_complete_macros_helper.rb) for `text_field_with_auto_complete`, then you will see that we can use the option `:after_update_element`. This option allows us to specify the name of the JavaScript function that will be called when the user selects one of the proposed values.

What we need to do:

1. write a JavaScript function that
   will display anywhere user-selected
   value from autocomplete field.
2. call `text_field_with_auto_complete`
   with `:after_update_element`

That's how the template will look like:

```
<ul id="selected_participant_container"></ul>

<%= text_field_with_auto_complete :participant, :name, {}, {
  :url => {:controller => "contentcom/discussions", :action => :get_users_for_auto_complete},
  :method => :get,
  :param_name => 'search',
  :after_update_element => 'afterParticipantSelected'
}%>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function afterParticipantSelected (el, value) {
    var container = document.getElementById ('selected_participant_container');

    container.innerHTML = value;
  }
</ Script>
```

Now, when a user selects a value in the autocomplete field, it will be displayed in the element with id = `selected_participant_container`

Of course, you can use methods that are proposed by tokland.

But I would Recommend you first learn the basics of HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Note first that the block of `button_to_function` (and its partial, of course) is generated **server-side**, so it has no way to know the value of the autocomplete in the client. You have 2 ways to accomplish what you want: create a RJS action for the auto_complete (if that's possible) or 2) use Javascript/AJAX and connect to the auto_complete URL, get the value and modify the DOM accordingly (also in JS).